# Deleting Non-empty Directory with smbclient

Tags: linux, shell, samba

How can I remove a non-empty directory with smbclient?

Comment: This site is for programming questions only: your question is off-topic.

Comment: @assylias:Thanks for the comment. However, I was going to use it in a shell script for a deployment purpose so it seemed to be programming related

Comment: you would probably get better answers on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Good advise. tnx again :)

Comment: The unix.stackexchange.com question is [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65855/deleting-non-empty-directory-with-smbclient)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably cannot do this with `smbclient`.  If you have superuser (a.k.a. root) access right on the local computer, you can mount remote directory using `smbmount` and then delete files from it using `rm -Rf`.